# Convert from txt to xml

Tags: java, xml, text, converters

I have a java code to convert txt file to xml file: (it works)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFile));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(toFile);
OutputFormat of = new OutputFormat("XML", "windows-1250", true);
of.setIndent(1);
of.setIndenting(true);
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(fos, of);
ContentHandler hd = serializer.asContentHandler();
hd.startDocument();
    AttributesImpl atts = new AttributesImpl();
    hd.startElement("", "", "CDR_FILES", atts);
    String line = null, tag;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals("Cdr File")) {
            line = in.readLine();
            hd.startElement("", "", "CDR", atts);
            int i = 0;
            while (!line.equals("Cdr File")) {
              if (i == 0)
                tag = "Record_No";
              else if (i == 1)
                tag = "Time";
              else if (i == 2)
                tag = "Serial_Number";
              else if (i == 3)
                tag = "Serial_Number_in_module";
```

This is my txt file:

```
Cdr File
1
Time=2010/02/15 17:15:17 
Serial_Number=1924891018
Serial_Number_in_module=282826228ff
Cdr File
2
Time=2010/02/15 17:15:17 
Serial_Number=1924891018
Serial_Number_in_module=283423627ff
...
```

I have 2 letters "ff" in Serial_Number_in_module, that I dont need to save in xml file.
Is it possible not to save this letters?

Comment: What is your problem? I do not see problem using just part of string when reading file - `String.substring() method`, or `String.replace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get the string from the file while reading and then write the condition for serial number

Example

```
String sample = "282826228ff";
String output = sample.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Output:
`282826228`